# Convert images to videos in iOS without locking UI Thread (Swift)

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to convert image snapshots into a video but I am facing UI Thread problems: my view controller is locked. I would like to know how to handle this because I did a lot of research and tried to detach the process into different DispatchQueues but none of them worked. So, it explains why I am not using any Queue on the code below:

```
class ScreenRecorder {
func renderPhotosAsVideo(callback: @escaping(_ success: Bool, _ url: URL)->()) {
        var frames = [UIImage]()
        for _ in 0..<100 {
            let image = self.containerView.takeScreenshot()
            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7), let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                frames.append(compressedImage)
            }
        }
        self.generateVideoUrl(frames: frames, complete: { (fileURL: URL) in
            self.saveVideo(url: fileURL, complete: { saved in
                print("animation video save complete")
                callback(saved, fileURL)
            })
        })
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.bounds.size)
        let image = renderer.image { _ in
            self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        return image
    }
}

class ViewController {
let recorder = ScreenRecorder()

        recorder.renderPhotoAsVideo { success, url in

            if (success) {
                print("ok")
            } else {
                self.alert(title: "Erro", message: "Nao foi possivel salvar o video", block: nil)
            }
        }
}
```

PS: I used this tutorial as reference ->  http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/05/21/swift-how-to-record-a-screen-video-or-convert-images-to-videos/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "none of them worked"?

Comment: I tried to detach every functionality in different queues with different QoS. Nothing, nada, zero

Answer (score 2):

It really looks like this is not possible, at least not the way you are trying to do it. 
There are quite a few ways to render a `UIView`s content into an image, but all of them `must be used from the main thread only`. This applies also to the `drawInHierarchy` method you are using.

As you have to call it on the main thread and the method is just getting called so many times, I think this will never work in a performant way.

See profiling in Instruments:
[image]

Sources:

- [How to render view into image faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066717/how-to-render-view-into-image-faster)
- [Safe way to render UIVIew to an image on background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348962/safe-way-to-render-uiview-to-an-image-on-background-thread)

Comment: In this case, takeScreenshot() should be done in Main Queue.

Comment: But isn't the render stuff something that should be done in a background thread?

Comment: I just updated my answer according to the new information I could gather from your repo and further tests I did. Unfortunately I think it's not possible to do it this way.